# Forcing Java lambda expressions to capture non-final variables in Java

Tags: java, lambda, final

Is it possible to have a lambda expression capture a variable that is not effectively final?

I know that my code would work perfectly if it could capture them, currently I have to create a new variable that copies the non-final variable I want to pass into a lambda expression.

```
final SomeClass otherObj;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int a = i;
    someObject.method(() -> otherObj.process(a, a+1))
}
```

I'd like to pass in  'i' instead of having to create a new temporary variable.

Comment: Please post an example to clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this with java8,

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i ->{
   someObject.method(() -> otherObj.process(i, i+1))
});
```

Comment: I kind of feel like that  this is identical to what I did, except that this is more elegant :D Something tells me that under the hood it is creating new temporary variables.

Answer (score 1):

I used the [`java.util.concurrent.atomic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package.

Here is an example:

```
        AtomicInteger tifCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
        try(DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("C:\\ImageStorage")) {
            ds.forEach(path -> {
                if (FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.tif").matches(path)) {
                    tifCount.incrementAndGet();
                }
            });
        }
```