# How to change an outside non final variable in Java lambdas

Tags: java

Let's imagine, i need a list of squares:

```
public static List<Integer> test1() {
   int i = 0;
   return IntStream.iterate(0, sqrt -> sqrt < 100, sqrt -> { ++i; return i*i; })
       .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

It'll fail with
`error: local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final`

Yes, I know, there are a lot of better ways to achieve the same result. For one:

```
public static List<Integer> test2() {
   return IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i < 10, i -> i+1).map(i -> i * i)
       .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I was able to rewrite all cases when I was tempted to reference a local variable in lambda.
But I'm curious anyway.

I do not need any help with fixing this particular code. And I don't even think that you should do something like this in real code. It's a **strictly theoretical** question:

*How it should be done, if I'll be forced to do this?

Hmm... will I ever really be forced to do this?*

(To change an outside variable in Java lambdas, I mean.)

For now I know of 3 way of changing outside variable in lambdas:

1. Wrap it in an array:

   ```
   public static List<Integer> test3() {
      int[] i = {0}
      return IntStream.iterate(0, sqrt -> sqrt < 100, sqrt -> { ++(i[0]); return i[0]*i[0]; })
          .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
   }
   ```

   Like here https://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-effectively-final-local-variables
   Which is ugly.
2. Convert local variable into an instance variable.
   Which is not only ugly, but also unsafe. (Same href)
3. Use `AtomicInteger` (or similar).
   Like here [Forcing Java lambda expressions to capture non-final variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31403049/forcing-java-lambda-expressions-to-capture-non-final-variables-in-java)
   Which is an overkill

All other answers to all other questions I read propose only these three solutions I don't find saticfactory, or they deal with constants and not mutable variables. Like here [How to use non final variable in Java 8 Lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36307541/how-to-use-non-final-variable-in-java-8-lambdas)

Any suggestion?

Comment: "*Let's imagine, i need something like this"* - Why do you need it, though? Lambdas stem from a functional background, i.e. their very nature is being free of side-effects. This does not mean that you cannot have side effects, but you should limit them. What you are trying to do is basically impossible without additional syntax.

Comment: Can you add the actual code you have to your question? This code can easily changed to a simple `for()` loop, where you don't have this problem. Post your code as a [mcve] until the point where you get the error message about a `final` reference.

Comment: @Turing85, all other, more realistic examples, were refactored

Comment: @Progman, as I said "I know, there are a lot of better ways to achieve the same result". It's a theoretical question. Added function() definitions to make it reproducible.

Comment: Yet another good example of something that’s accomplished better with a simple loop.  Just because streams and lambdas are fun doesn’t mean they should be treated as a golden hammer.

Comment: There is a lot in programming that we could do, but we don't. Uncle Bob once said that when you look at the history in programming, we limited ourselves in what to do. If you need to *force* the solution, then there is probably a better way to do it. In short: I do not think that you will ever be *forced* to do it in exactly this way.

Comment: @VGR, yes, you are right. But the mystery remains :) Is it even possible to do nicely?

Comment: @x00 You can try providing a custom seed object for the `Stream.iterate()` method which holds the state during the iteration.

Comment: Why have I got the feeling that whatever is proposed, it won't be accepted unless it's the thing that has been defined to not be possible? You've already dismissed 3 perfectly fine - if "ugly" - workarounds, it seems to me. Workarounds, by definition, are a bit yucky. If they weren't, they would probably not be called workarounds but "options".

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica, well, if there is no nice way to do this, then I promise to accept any other way besides these three :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Stream.iterate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#iterate-T-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method to provide a custom `seed` object, which will be used in your iterations. You can fill the object with all the state information you need and access it from inside the actual iteration function/method/lambda. It can look like this:

The state object:

```
public class SeedObject {
    public final int state;

    public final int value;

    public SeedObject(int state, int value) {
        this.state = state;
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.state+"|"+this.value; 
    }
}
```

Using the `iterate()` method with the new class.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    List<SeedObject> result = Stream.iterate(new SeedObject(1,1), last -> {
        int next = last.state+1;
        return new SeedObject(next, next*next);
    })
    .limit(10)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

This will result in the following output:

```
[1|1, 2|4, 3|9, 4|16, 5|25, 6|36, 7|49, 8|64, 9|81, 10|100]
```

From there you can convert the list as you like and/or read the last state from the last element of the list. This way your iteration and your lambda states "inside" the `iterate()` call and do not have any access to the "outside".

Comment: No one in their right mind will exchange `int[] i` for this :) But I must admit, it looks... beautiful. I think, I'll accept that.